# Get data from a table after joining based on null value of joined table using LINQ

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, join, asp.net-web-api

I have some tables like `"Job" "AppliedJob" "JobOffer" "Contract" "Employeer"`
[image]

Description: When employeer post job it is stored in "Job" table with his ID. If a freelancer apply to the job it is stored in "AppliedJob" table with his ID. Then Employeer sees the application and send offer to the freelancer and it is stored in "JobOffer" table. If freelancer accept the offer it is then stored in "Contract" table. At first in "Contract" ContractID, OfferID and StratDate are stored and CompletedDate is stored as null. When the contract is completed the CompletedDate  field is modified with date.
Want: I want to return all jobs with no completed contract
I tried:

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/PrivateApi/GetEmployeerPostedJob/")]
    public object GetEmployeerPostedJob(int id)
    {

        var data = (from j in db.Jobs
                    where j.EmployeerID == id
                    join apl in db.AppliedJobs
                    on j.JobID equals apl.JobID
                    join o in db.JobOffers
                    on apl.AppliedJobID equals o.AppliedJobID
                    join con in db.Contracts
                    on o.OfferID equals con.OfferID
                    where con.CompletedDate == null



                    select new
                    {
                        j.JobTitle,
                        j.JobID,
                        j.Budget,
                        j.Deadline,
                        j.Employeer,
                        j.JobDetails,
                        j.PublishDate,
                        j.ReqSkill,
                        j.NoOFFreelancer,
                        j.Preference,
                        Category1=j.Category,
                       totalAppliedFreelancer=(from aple in db.AppliedJobs where j.JobID ==aple.JobID select aple).Count(),

                        Category = (from gg in db.Categories where gg.CategoryID == j.Category select gg.CategoryName).FirstOrDefault()

                    }).ToList();


        return data.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

But it returns no jobs.
How can i get all jobs which are not completed yet(CompletedDate == null in Contract table)?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to show the employeer's posted jobs on his page but only those jobs that are not completed

The above (die to one to many relationships involved) can be paraphrased as

*return all jobs with **no completed contract***

while the way you wrote the query, besides the possible data duplication, it answers the question

*return all jobs with **existing, but not completed contract***

i.e. is missing the jobs w/o applied job, applied job w/o offer and offer w/o contract.

The correct query would be something like this:

```
from job in db.Jobs
where job.EmployeerID == id
join jobContract in (
   from appliedJob in db.AppliedJobs
   join offer in db.JobOffers on appliedJob.AppliedJobID equals offer.AppliedJobID
   join contract in db.Contracts on offer.OfferID equals contract.OfferID
   select new { appliedJob, offer, contract }
) on job.JobID equals jobContract.appliedJob.JobID into jobContracts
where !jobContracts.Any(jobContract => jobContract.contract.CompletedDate != null)
select ...
```

The query could further be simplified by using [navigation properties](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/), but since I don't see navigation properties between `AppliedJob` and `JobOffer`, I'm leaving that for you.

**Update:** Here is the same query with navigation properties (by simplified I meant no need for `join` operators):

```
from job in db.Jobs
let completedContracts =
    from appliedJob in job.AppliedJobs
    from offer in appliedJob.JobOffers
    from contract in offer.Contracts
    where contract.CompletedDate != null
    select contract
where !completedContracts.Any()
select ...
```

Comment: How can i make navigation property?

Comment: The same way as you did the other - I see a lot like `Job.AppliedJobs`, `AppliedJob.Job`, `JobOffer.Contracts` etc.

Comment: But AppliedJobs has for fK with Job, JobOffer has FK with AppliedJob, Contract has FK with JobOffer. But how can i make relation with Job and Contract as they are not directly connected?

Comment: You can't. I meant connecting `AppliedJob` with `JobOffer` which is not seen in the posted class diagram.

Comment: Can you explain this, please? `where !jobContracts.Any(jobContract => jobContract.contract.CompletedDate != null) `

Comment: Well, it's basically how you read it - "there are no pending contracts". so either there are no contracts at all, or all contracts are not completed. `Any` is needed mainly because your design allows multiple contracts per job.

Comment: I forgot to make relation with AppliedJob and JobOffer. I edited my post with new image. You said "The query could further be simplified by using navigation properties". Now i have navigation property. How can i make the query easy now? @ Ivan Stoev

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618579/get-data-with-sum-from-a-table-after-multiple-joining-using-linq?noredirect=1#comment70440048_41618579

Comment: Can you have a look on this question? @Ivan Stoev

Answer (score 0):

This LINQ query doesn't work on live server (sql-2008)     But works on my local VS 2013. Is there any mistake if my live database is empty at first time?
@Ivan Stoev

public object BrowseJobs()
        {

```
        var skills = db.Skills.ToDictionary(d => d.SkillID, n => n.SkillName);

        var jobData = (from j in db.Jobs where j.Preference==2
                       //from cj in j.ClosedJobs.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                       join cj in db.ClosedJobs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       on j.JobID equals cj.JobID into closedJob
                       where !closedJob.Any()
                       join c in db.Categories on j.Category equals c.CategoryID

                       join jobContract in
                           (
                               from appliedJob in db.AppliedJobs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               from offer in appliedJob.JobOffers.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                               from contract in db.Contracts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               select new { appliedJob, offer, contract }
                               ).DefaultIfEmpty()
                       on j.JobID equals jobContract.appliedJob.JobID into jobContracts
                       where !jobContracts.Any(jobContract => jobContract.contract.CompletedDate != null)

                       select new
                       {

                           JobTitle = j.JobTitle,
                           JobID = j.JobID,
                           ReqSkillCommaSeperated = j.ReqSkill,
                           Category = c.CategoryName,
                           Budget=j.Budget,
                           Deadline=j.Deadline, 
                           JobDetails=j.JobDetails,
                           PublishDate=j.PublishDate,
                           TotalApplied=(from ap in db.AppliedJobs where j.JobID == ap.JobID select ap.AppliedJobID).DefaultIfEmpty().Count()

                       }).AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => new
            {
                JobID = x.JobID,
                JobTitle = x.JobTitle,
                Category = x.Category,
                Budget = x.Budget,
                Deadline = x.Deadline,
                JobDetails = x.JobDetails,
                PublishDate = x.PublishDate,
                SkillNames = GetSkillName(x.ReqSkillCommaSeperated, skills),
                TotalApplied = (from ap in db.AppliedJobs where x.JobID == ap.JobID select ap.AppliedJobID).DefaultIfEmpty().Count()
            }).ToList();


        return jobData.AsEnumerable();
    }
```